# How do I assign a value from another value in the same column based on the nearest date?

Tags: python, pandas, date, nearest-neighbor

I want to replace some values that are currently 0(column C) with the values(column C) that are closest to the date(Date column), based on similar variable grouping(column Type)

I have researched about .index.get_loc(df, method = "nearest") 
but no luck in applying it in my code.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['2018-12-29',5,6,5,'cc'],
                           ['2019-01-05',1,2,0,'cc'],
                           ['2018-12-29',3,4,10,'cc'],
                           ['2019-01-01',1,2,0,'bb'],
                           ['2018-12-29',3,4,20,'bb'],
                           ['2019-01-10',7,9,5,'bb']]),
                columns =['Date','A','B','C','Type'])


#      Date     A   B   C      Type
#0  2018-12-29  5   6   5.0     cc
#1  2019-01-05  1   2   0       cc
#2  2018-12-29  3   4   10.0    cc
#3  2019-01-01  1   2   0       bb
#4  2018-12-29  3   4   20.0    bb
#5  2019-01-10  7   9   5.0     bb
```

How can i:
 1) assign the the first None to be the average of the same date values with same Type 'cc'
 2) Assign second None to the nearest date with similar Type 'bb'

```
#      Date     A   B   C      Type
#0  2018-12-29  5   6   5.0     cc
#1  2019-01-05  1   2   7.5     cc
#2  2018-12-29  3   4   10.0    cc
#3  2019-01-01  1   2   20.0    bb
#4  2018-12-29  3   4   20.0    bb
#5  2019-01-10  7   9   5.0     bb
```

Comment: How do you get 7.5 for the second record?

Comment: interpolate or mean?